# Use of unresolved identifier self

Tags: swift, xcode

This error keeps popping up in my code and I need to know what to do about it. I'm still a newbie, so if you want to give me tips on how to code in Swift, I'll be happy to see them

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Here's my code:

```html
import ReachabilitySwift

class ReachabilityManager: NSObject {
    static  let shared = ReachabilityManager()  
    }

    var isNetworkAvailable : Bool {
        return reachabilityStatus != .notReachable
    }

    var reachabilityStatus: Reachability.NetworkStatus = .notReachable

    let reachability = Reachability()!
    func reachabilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
        let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
        switch reachability.currentReachabilityStatus {
        case .notReachable:
            debugPrint("Network became unreachable")
        case .reachableViaWiFi:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through WiFi")
        case .reachableViaWWAN:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through Cellular Data")
        }
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
        do{
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Could not start reachability notifier")
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the code? AppDelegate? playground?

Comment: Do you want the whole thing?

Comment: Because this is where the error is

Comment: not really, but we need to know the surroundings/environment of the code. because it says self is not defined. so we need to know how self is getting set

Comment: Looks like you are trying to add this code outside of a class, just tested it in actual project - works fine. However, if I'm adding it outside the class I'm (obliviously) getting your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation happens when `self` is not defined, please make sure that you are trying to add `startMonitoring()` function to a class, extension or struct's scope.

Comment: I added the function to a class, but it still gives me the error

Comment: According to the code you posted you added extra `}` after `static  let shared = ReachabilityManager()` which is closing ReachabilityManager class scope.

Comment: @ClaireCho try to remove extra `}` after `static let shared = ReachabilityManager()` and add it to the end of the class, it should help.